# Set Alphabet A-Z to specific int value instead of the ASCII values JAVA

Tags: java, char, character, ascii

i had to solve following problem:

I need to get an specific int number from a character. But not with the ASCII int values.(Would be to easy)

For example: i know 'A' is 65 in ASCII. But i need it to set the value from 'A' to 1 or 10 or whatever without using the ASCII. 
So in this case, all chars of the alphabet should be a value from 1'A'-26'Z'.

I have some ideas but i think they're to comlpicated like the switch (x) argument with 26 cases like ... case 'A': z=1;break; etc. (but to inefficient if you iterate some times).

I know there's a way to solve it without ascii and switch... which i forgot. But i dont know for what catchword i need to search for.
I dont want a full solution as more like little hints or food for thought.

Thanks for every answer.

Greetz from Germany

Comment: Why not get the ascii int value and subtract an appropriate constant? In short, **why** do you need this?

Comment: You can just use  `int charInt = 'A' - 64;// output = 1` where `A` can be any upper letter

Comment: Why don't you try using `enum`?

Comment: From `char x;` you can calculate `int z = x - 'A' + 1;`

Comment: It sounds like your switch statement might be the way to go. Is this a homework problem?

Comment: Ok is an possibility.  I need to create a programm which calculates checksums for IBAN based on the countrycode. The calclulation should be like A=1 // 1+9 to get double digit checksums. So i need to set the chars to static specific int numbers like A=1...Z=26.

Comment: Yes exactly that what Thomas Fritsch written was the solution i searched for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest `Map<Character, Integer>`. You can assign Integer values to Characters and you can always get it with simple getValue() method from Map interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `enum`. When you use a constructor for an enum you can assign a desired value to each letter.

```
public enum Alphabet {
    A(1), B(2), C(3), D(4), ... Z(26);

    private int _value;

    Alphabet(int value) {
        _value = value;
    }

    public int value() {
        return _value;
    }
}
```

---

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Simple put all letters in array with appropriate sequence

```
class Alphabet {
        private final char[] alphabet;
        
        public Alphabet(String letters) {
            alphabet = letters.toCharArray();
        }
        
        public char letterBy(int number) {
            return alphabet[number - 1];
        }

        public int length() { 
            return alphabet.length;
        }
        
 }
```

in case you put **ABC** letters you able to retrieve them by numbers **A-1 B-2 C-3**, in method letterBy() we decrement number because arrays have numeration from 0. Also we have method that return amount of letters in alphabet.